# Gatsby Static Sites with Javascript Disabled

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, progressive-enhancement, graceful-degradation

Is it possible to use Gatsby to generate static sites that can be viewed with Javascript disabled in the browser?

I heard that Gatsby sites could be accessed in this way but I've tried various Gatsby starters including [gatsby-starter-default](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default) and [gatsby-advanced-starter](https://github.com/Vagr9K/gatsby-advanced-starter) and all of them will only show the index page when Javascript is disabled. Link clicks return white screens.

I'm just looking for some graceful degradation here - I only need the basic pages and images to render, nothing more.

Comment: Gatsby will not generate any html files in development. Try to build production assets and serve that and see if it works without JavaScript.

Comment: I've already tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: How could a React-based site work without JS?

Comment: React is used by Gatsby to build static sites. Static sites are usually able to render in the browser without Javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatsby is generating critical portions of the app that are shown on page load and then "hydrates" the page with React, meaning that it first shows critical HTML and CSS and only after that load dynamic parts of the site. So if you use some additional react components which could not be prerendered they will not work but the site as a whole should work.

If you are using service workers and disabled JS from devtools than it could be a cache issue. Try to disable javascript from the browser preferences and run the website from the incognito window without devtools open. GatsbyJS based website should work.

But, your website will be faster and use less data with PWA and service workers enabled, which do need javascript.

Comment: Tried disabling Javascript from browser preferences and running incognito, as you suggested, and still doesn't work. I just get 'This app works best with JavaScript enabled.'. This is with a fresh install of the latest Gatsby. I'll investigate their docs and see if there's a way to get the page to render without JS.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/9626#issuecomment-435605109